# Getting Correlation failed exception during OIDC auth

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, identityserver4, implicit

Right now I am developing asp net core 2.0 web site and I am adding authorization.
I have existing auth server build using identity server 4. I added new client with **Implicit** grant type. When I run locally I am successfully redirected to identity server and than after login back to we site. But when I deployed web site I am getting

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
Exception: Correlation failed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler+<HandleRequestAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
```

when redirected back after login. What can case the issue ?
Btw, here is my startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";

        })
       .AddCookie(options =>
       {
           options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
           options.Cookie.Name = "mvcimplicit";
       })
       .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
       {
           options.Authority = "https://identity.************.com/";
           options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
           options.ClientId = "mvc.client";         
           options.SaveTokens = true;
       });
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {           
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

Do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

May be you have some sort of cluster without exlicity defined data protection? Its potentially can produce behaviour like you describe.